# Drag And Drop image upload does not have a temp location or a name (it does not get uploaded)

Tags: javascript, php, drag-and-drop

I am using [CSS-Trick](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/)'s Drag and Drop upload, but it doesn't quite work as I thought. I am saving the uploaded image with PHP, the following code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    function upload($file_temp, $file_extn) {
    $file_path = 'i/' . uniqid() . '.' . $file_extn;
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
        if(file_exists($file_path)) {
            //header('Location: ' . $file_path);
        }
  }
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    //$file_name = uniqid() . '.png';
    echo 'Filename is ' . $file_name . '<br>';
  //$file_extn = strtolower(explode('.', $file_name));
    $file_extn = end((explode(".", $file_name)));

  $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    echo 'Filetemp is ' . $file_temp . '<br>';

    if(!empty($file_temp) && !empty($file_name)) {
        if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed)) {
          upload($file_temp, $file_extn);
        } else {
          echo "The filetype '" . $file_extn . "' is not allowed<br>The allowed filetypes are: ";
          echo implode(', ', $allowed);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error';
    }
}
```

My problem is, that when I Drag and Drop an image to the site - [found here, so you can try it yourself](http://albert-websites.com/images/) - the form is auto-submitted, but it is like the file was not attached correctly. As seen in the PHP script above, I try to `echo` the name and the temp location of the file, both required to save the file. But, they're both empty. It is like the image does not get attached correctly, but I cannot see why here. I use Ajax so submit the form, and it works just fine when I choose the file manually, clicking "Choose a file".

So, somehow the Drag And Drop attachment of the image is incorrect - but as I am not quite a "JavaScript genius" here, I cannot see what would be wrong here. I might be missing the obvious, but I doubt it, as I have changed very few lines from CSS-Trick's JavaScript - and most of it was pure preferably styling.

Comment: I'm getting "Filename is loader.gif
Filetemp is /tmp/phpXnBsW7". Not empty for me?

Comment: It's only when I drag and drop it, that it doesn't get attached correctly. Not when you do it manually.

Comment: I understand... Dragging and dropping a file onto the site you provided is working for me.

Comment: This is what I get: https://i.gyazo.com/0894c606045a6168e9e6f696b2e4d5cf.png On firefox.